# About Density and continuous and open function.

Tags: general-topology

I've seen a proposition like that
Proposition: If $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ is an open and continuous function and $D$ is dense in $Y$, then $f^{-1}(D)$ is dense in $X$.

Is that proposition correct? if so, here is my approach :
if $D$ is dense in $Y$, then for all nonempty open $G$ in $X$, $f(G)\cap D\neq\emptyset$ then $f^{-1}(f(G)\cap D)\neq\emptyset$ so $f^{-1}(f(G))\cap f^{-1}(D)\neq\emptyset$, then $G\cap f^{-1}(D)\subseteq f^{-1}(f(G))\cap f^{-1}(D)$. So how can I guarantee that $G\cap f^{-1}(D)\neq\emptyset$ or any solution for that?

Comment: See the first answer to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/74415/is-the-preimage-of-the-closure-the-closure-of-the-preimage-under-a-quotient-map

Comment: @DouglasMolin Click the "share" link of the answer you want to link to to get the url of the  answer.

Comment: thank you so  much, but which part exactly do I need to use in the first answer? there are many equivalence though. @DouglasMolin

Comment: Can you please explain it ? @DouglasMolin

Comment: If you know that for an open map the preimage of the closure is the closure of the preimage (see the link), then you can conclude that $\overline{f^{-1}(D)}=f^{-1}(\overline{D})=f^{-1}(Y)=X,$ i.e. $f^{-1}(D)$ is dense.

Comment: Aww I totally focused on other conclusions, that’s the case, thank you so much sir @DouglasMolin

Comment: [The inverse image of dense set is dense and of a comeager set is comeager?.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1220475/the-inverse-image-of-dense-set-is-dense-and-of-a-comeager-set-is-comeager) addresses your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know $f[G] \cap D \neq \emptyset$ by openness of $f$ and denseness of $D$ and if $x \in G$ so that $f(x) \in D$ (which must exist) then $x \in G \cap f^{-1}[D]$ by definition so that $f^{-1}[D]$ indeed intersects all non-empty open subsets of $X$, as required.

That's all there is to it.

Comment: Or equivalently we can say that if $U$ were a non-empty open subset of $X$ and if $U$ were disjoint from $f^{-1}D$ then $f[U]$ would be  non-empty, open in $Y,$ and disjoint from $D.$

Comment: Thank you so much sir @HennoBrandsma

Comment: But isnt it true when the function $f$ is one-to-one? @DanielWainfleet?

Comment: @Dans0804 For $U \cap f^{-1}[D] = \emptyset \implies f[U] \cap D = \emptyset$ we don't need any assumption on $f$ at all. Just the definitions. My solution is just the contrapositive formulation.

Comment: your solution is okay sir, but  but Do I know it wrong? if $U\cap f^{-1}(D)=\emptyset$ then yes $f(U\cap f^{-1}(D))=\emptyset$ so, $f(U\cap f^{-1}(D))\subseteq f(U)\cap f( f^{-1}(D)\subseteq f(U)\cap D$ isnt it like that? how can we conclude that $f(U)\cap D=\emptyset$ if $f$ is not one-to-one and onto? @HennoBrandsma